# ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME loading a css

Tags: php, css

I have an old Joomla site, and I would need to check its layout and take a screen capture.

Actually I restored all the files and database on a xampp 1.8.0, locally on my pc.
Then I obviously changed some configurations inside the configuration.php to meet xampp path and db user.

If I try to browse to the site home, in the Chrome developer tools, I get ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME, relative to some css files.
I don't understand which is exactly the reason of this error.... the css files are present in the directory.

Any idea about this error?
Kind regards,
Matt

Comment: Is there a url reported with the error?  What is it?  What is the referenced url within the html?

Comment: localhost:8080/domaintest/templates/egHome/css/template_css.css ....and the file, as I said, is really present in such a directory

Comment: Are you prefixing the URL with `http://`? There's a bug in Chromium with how it handles sites without protocols, that resurfaced in Chromium 40+. Try prefixing with `http://` and see if that resolves the issue for you :)

Comment: Hi @ObsidianAge, your suggestion worked fine.

Comment: Awesome, glad that solved your problem -- I've made an answer for this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a long-standing bug in Chromium regarding how links without protocols are handled. It occasionally is patched, but seems to keep resurfacing.

Prefixing your links with `http://` (or `https://`) should resolve the issue for you:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/domaintest/templates/egHome/css/template_css.‌​css">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I don't know what that Chromium bug is about exactly but `localhost:8080/domaintest/templates/egHome/css/template_css.‌​css` is, if not an invalid URL, at least not the OP thinks (it'd be a relative URL pointing to e.g. `http://example.com/localhost:8080/domaintest/templates/egHome/css/template_css.‌​css`).